# JQuery causing postback in .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I created an adrotator in jquery for the first time and when I use it on a page that uses pagemethods to do ajax calls to the server and show a modal. The page posts back. When I remove the rotator the page works as it should. In the rotator I have the following code in the document ready function.

```
    $(".animation_control a.play").live('click', function () {        
        $(this).removeClass('play');
        $(this).addClass('pause');
        Play();
    });

    $(".animation_control a.pause").live('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('pause');
        $(this).addClass('play');
        clearInterval(timer);
    });

    $(".animation_control a.pause").click(function () {

    });

    //Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function () {
        $(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
        $("a.collapse").toggleClass("show");
    });
```

If I comment out this code the page stops the complete page refresh and and posts back async like it should. Any ideas on why this would cause the page to do a complete postback instead of a partial one?

Comment: When does the POST happen?  All that code does is set up some event handlers; it won't cause a form to be submitted or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

As a guess, since the code is incomplete, you should add `return false` to your event handlers to prevent the links from actually firing.

Answer (score 2):

```
.live('click', function (e) {       
e.preventDefault();

//your code
```

Comment: That didnt work but that is the right track, if I change live to click then the postback doesn't happen. Just the element is added dynamically so I need the live event. Any other ideas? I also tried adding return false to the call and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors are used to navigate to a page/region in the same page, and according to this part, clicking an anchor MUST move us to the HREF that the anchor is pointing to.

in order to cancle this default behavior, we will need to do either `return false` or to prevent the default action using jQuery.

This is [an example of what i mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/T57yj/5/)

Comment: The page works fine with out the .live delegates, once I removed them it worked the way it should. The only problem is, I need those delegates, just not sure how to make they work. As suggested I tried return false, and also e.preventDefault();

Comment: @user647078 : I reviewed your link, you were missing a closing bracket, and after it, everything is working perfect.

give it a try from here again : [Revised example](http://jsfiddle.net/T57yj/19/)
"dont forget to mark as answer if it helped you :)"